# Android Studio Build Failed : Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' - All projects stopped working

Tags: android, gradle

All projects were working fine previously but have all suddenly stopped working. This error is displayed when building any project in the Android Studio.

I did not make any changes to what was previously working. So, I also don't know what triggered this.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Users\DELL14\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output  D:\AndroidDevelopment\Sunshine\Lynx09\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=D:\AndroidDevelopment\Sunshine\Lynx09\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
1
Output:
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

This is what was in the gradle console for a different project. Its almost the same for all of the projects I try to run.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\DELL14\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --output D:\AndroidDevelopment\Sunshine\Sunshine\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-8197c74ea8b8656ed6c95d15295a239b84e4ed49.jar C:\Users\DELL14\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\21.0.3\support-annotations-21.0.3.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.


    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug      option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 32.438 secs
```

Comment: Make sure you have sdk in the  specified path

Comment: post your gradle console error

Comment: @RamBabuPudari There's the gradle console error.

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
} try with this and remove ur annotation jar or path from

Comment: where do i add the dependencies? in the build.gradle file for the project?